# Tailwind flex-grow not expanding to the remaining screen space

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

I am trying to display three columns as inline using flex class of tailwind css (I am fairly new to tailwind). While doing so, the third column is not expanding to the full width of the screen.

Here is my HTML snippet -

```
<div class="container flex flex-row w-screen">
    <div class="basis-1/5"></div>
    <div class="basis-1/5"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow"></div>
</div>
```

Up until 1280px of width size, everything is working as intended. Above 1280px, I am getting this issue.

I have tried using `flex-1` as well, but the issue persisted.

[Here is the screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gajpb.png)

Kindly let me know if you need any further information on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider removing the `container` class. This class has `max-width` declarations applied preventing the element it is applied to from respecting its `width` property:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row w-screen">
  <div class="basis-1/5 h-10 bg-red-200"></div>
  <div class="basis-1/5 h-10 bg-red-300"></div>
  <div class="flex-grow h-10 bg-red-400"></div>
</div>
```